# Where can I find directions for Xamarin publishing to Apple Store

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, apple-watch

I'm looking at building a Watch App as an independent project and would be developing this with VS and Xamarin but all I can find on the web involves publishing of apps to Apple Store via a Mac which I do not have and would just as soon not purchase just to publish the Watch App when it is ready to be put out.

Could someone point me towards a guide for doing this from a Windows box and the in's and out's of the process coming from this side of the world?

Comment: You have to have a Mac.

Comment: As @lex said, no getting around having a macos device available.

Comment: Apple does not allow publishing of apps for the store from other than MacOS devices. If you're going to develop and publish for Apple, you've got to be using one of their products.

Comment: Mac required: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/

Comment: The publication process is the same for Xamarin apps.  But like everyone else is telling you, you need a Mac.  All of the build chain tools and SDKs are provided by Apple, and only run on a Mac.

Comment: Also, it sounds like your planning to do a Apple Watch _only_ if I'm not mistaken every Watch app needs to have a regular app as well.

Comment: In concept could do a phone piece to go with it. If that is what it takes that is what it takes.  I guess I will have to figure out a way to get a Mac up and going.

Comment: @KenWhite If you'd like to file an answer I'd be happy to give one of you credit.You were first with a fully response but SushiHangover did as well and included the xamarian guides reference as well so I would see both of you as giving great responses but since they were not posted as 'answers I have nothing to flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow publishing of apps for the store from other than MacOS devices, which is mentioned in the Xamarin documentation on [Publishing to the App Store](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/). If you're going to develop and publish for Apple, you've got to be using one of their products.

Comment: Thanks Ken... I really wanted you to get credit for your answer even though I HATED IT LOL ... really irritates me that Apple forces me to use a Mac to push software for the watch, but that is what it is.  I just have to now figure out how to get a Mac up as inexpensively on my home network as possibly that is capable of pushing this.  Appreciate everyone's responses.